# dealloc called delay after dismissviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsnotificationcenter

I use AViewController to present BViewController.

I use AVPlayer on B, and use some `dispatch_after` for 3 seconds. and some NSNotification, observer.

When I hit my custom dismiss button, in my dismiss method, I remove NSNotification, Observer, even call `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];` when it already navigate to AViewController, i see the network status still spining on the iPhone's system status bar. after 2 - 5 seconds(it depends), I can see the `dealloc` was called from the log.

```
- (void)dismissThisViewController {
    NSLog(@"dismiss");
    [self deinitTimer];
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    if (self.videoPlaying) {
        [self pause];
    }
    [self.rsPlayer removeTimeObserver:self.timeObserver];
    [self.rsPlayer.currentItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
    [self.rsPlayer.currentItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"loadedTimeRanges"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
//dealloc
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog("dealloc");
}
```

What should I do to make it right? Destroy BViewController immediately after I navigate to AViewController. Because I might present the BViewController after I navagate from BViewController to A immediately.

Update:

By set a breakpoint to `dealloc()` method, I got this.
[image]

I did have a NSTimer, but i've already release it.

```
- (void)deinitTimer {
    if (self.timer) {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }
}
```

New found: I have MBProgressHUD, when this shows, I dismiss, it will delay a few seconds to dealloc.

What can I do with this situation?

Comment: add a breakpoint on `dealloc`, check who calls it so you know where is the last reference of `BViewController`

Comment: @BryanChen Thanks. It works. Please help me with a deeper problem?